# How to compare two input boxes in a variable table of input boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to alert when a input box is greater than a second box, in example:

```
<td align="center"> <input type='text' name='cantidad{{=i+1}}' id='cantidad' value='{{=(x.cantidad)}}' size='3' readonly="readonly"  /></td>

<td align="center"> <input type='text' name='desp{{=i+1}}' id='desp' value='' size='3' required='required' placeholder='Numero' onBlur="return validar(event)"/></td>
```

I have x set of input boxes, among these, the last two input boxes that I need check that the second can't be greater than the first. Then I can't figure out how catch these values in table that can be x set of them

The `{{}}` code is Python Embedded.

Edited: There are 12 input boxes for each row
Edited: I need that input with id='desp' can't be greater that the input with the id='cantidad' on every row

Comment: Are there only two of them per row?

Comment: Are the IDs `cantidad#` or just `cantidad` for all of them?

Comment: No, they are twelve for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by giving the ID's something like this:-

```
if(document.getElementById("first").value == document.getElementById("second").value){
//they are the same, do stuff for the same
}else if(document.getElementById("first").value >= document.getElementById("second").value
//first is more than second
}
```

or you can do something like this in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/su__/dtUUJ/)

Answer (score 0):

If you add a css class to the last textbox, say we call it "textbox-last", then you can use jQuery to bind a function to the blur event as follows:

```
$('#yourtable').on('blur', '.textbox-last', function() {

    var td = $(this).parent();
    var prevTextboxValue = td.prev().find('input').val();

    ...

});
```

That gets you the value from the previous textbox for any textbox that has the class on it. Then add whatever logic you want to implement after that.